# Lotus script to delete mass domino directory users from Excel file

Tags: lotus-domino

I need a lotus script for mass deletion of users from domino directory. I've found this script below which activates adminp request to delete domino users exported from CSV file but it actually doesn't delete any user from directory although domino reports successful deletion of users.
What am I doing wrong or is there any way to delete users immediately without activating adminp requests?

```
    Sub Initialize
   
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db,addbk As NotesDatabase
    Dim usrvw As NotesView
    Dim Username As String
    Dim    delcounter As Integer
   
    Dim nap As NotesAdministrationProcess
    Dim FIleNumber As Integer
    Dim Filename As String
   
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase   

   
    'Getting Address book.
    Set addbk=session.GetDatabase("Server Name","names.nsf",0)
    'To locally test enter server as blank Ex: "".
    Set usrvw=addbk.getview("$NamesFieldLookup")

    'If $NamesFieldLookup is not in the database, please use the different 'view which is sorted on the name format we have in .csv file.
   
    'Creating a file accesser
    filenumber%=FreeFile()
    fileName$="File Path"
    'Example: D:\usrdel.csv 
    Open fileName For Input As fileNumber%
   
    On Error Resume next
   
    delcounter=0
    Do Until EOF(fileNumber%)
        Input #fileNumber%,Username
        delcounter=delcounter+1
        Call nap.DeleteUser(Username, True , MAILFILE_DELETE_ALL , "Description about deletion",False)
        'notesAdministrationProcess.DeleteUser( username$ , immediate , mailfileaction% , denygroup$ [ , deletewindowsuser ] )
        'mailfileaction% :
        'MAILFILE_DELETE_ALL (2) deletes the mail file On the user's home server and all replicas. 
        'MAILFILE_DELETE_HOME (1) deletes the mail file On the user's home server. 
        'MAILFILE_DELETE_NONE (0) leaves the user's mail file. 
        'Use the required option.
        Print "Deleted " & CStr(delcounter) " Users"
    Loop   
   
End Sub
```

Comment: And did you do a 'tell adminp process all' command on the server console to initiate processing of the sequence of requests?

Comment: Yes, I have all the rights - localdomain administrator and full access administration. Of course I executed every time "tell adminp process all" command from console.

Comment: @TorstenLink In which part of lotus script code I am missing initialization of the nap instance - set nap= something or?

Comment: As shown in the exampe I linked: `Set nap = _
  session.CreateAdministrationProcess("myServer/northeast")`

Comment: Thanx @TorstenLink! Set nap =session.CreateAdministrationProcess("myServer/myServerDomain") - definitely solved the problem. Now it works!

Comment: Also tried to use this script for moving mail files from one directory to another. Instead of  using method "notesAdministrationProcess.DeleteUser" I've used  method "noteID$ = notesAdministrationProcess .MoveMailUser( username$ , newhomeserver$ , newhomeservermailpath$ )" - where is "username$" - Username; "newhomeserver$" - myServer/myServerDomain and "newhomeservermailpath$" - moved - folder which I previously created to move mail files from default mail folder "mail". Domino didn't report any error but script doesn't move user's mail files.  What is missing am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please create a new question for this